Using a for loop to iterate through a df to make comparison between models (OLS and anova_lm with statsmodel)
Hi guys I'm on my way with ISLP and I'm learning alot.
I'm doing an exercise (cap 3, 9, i) that asks to see if there is a relation between the predictors and the model using anova_lm.
I don' t get the point to do such thing instead of an F and anyway with a full model one would get the point. Anyway I'm wondering if I could loop through the columns and make for each loop a comparison between the null model and the fitted model with one predictor.
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
from ISLP.models import ModelSpec as MS
from statsmodels.stats.anova import anova_lm
df = pd.DataFrame('df.csv',  na_values=['?'])   # na_values= change any '?' in nan
y= df['response']```

# null model (only the intercept).
Xinter = pd.DataFrame({'intercept': np.ones(397, dtype= 'float')}) # (df has 397 rows)
fit_inter = sm.OLS(y , Xinter)  
ris_inter = fit_inter.fit()

# subset of columns of my df
df_colonne_rimaste = df.columns.drop(['response']))

#iteration through df_colonne_rimaste
for i in df_colonne_rimaste:
  print(i)  # see the column I'm working with
  X = MS(i).fit_transform(df)  # construct the model matrix
  modelx = sm.OLS(y, X, missing='drop') # specify the model
  resultx = modelx.fit()  # estimate parameters
  print('Confronto tra modello nullo e modello con ', i, 'risulta: \n {}').format(anova_lm(ris_inter, resultx))

# I get this meaage: 
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

I tried other stuff I can'tremember anymore. I tried hard.
Where is the problem? 
Thanks alot


include the full traceback or at least the last part that shows where the exception is raised. Check each piece in the loop, e.g. what shape is X. It's impossible or difficult to guess what or where something might break (without running the example and debugging.)

@josef I solved it.  After dropping rows the index doesn't update so then even if the dfs have the same number of observations the loop doesn't work. What shall I do? Cancel the question, submit the answer, what?

I think answering your question will be useful. The behavior with dropping rows will not be obvious and I have not seen a related question yet. Still add the traceback do your question, because that is what users often use to search.

@Josef What is a traceback?

When you get an exception in Python like the IndexError, then python shows the code path and at the last line of the traceback shows where the error was raised. This shows at which part we need to start investigating further to find the problem.

Problem solved.
As it seems when dropping rows the index seems to not reload. So the index of X and y couldn' t match
As computations with statsmodels and pandas actually seem to be in some way index based, resetting the index on X and y (.reset_index()) did the job.
Thanks alot
